# If an ordered rng $A$ has a upper or lower bound, then $A = {0}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, rngs, upper-lower-bounds

Let $m$ be the upper bound of $A$. Then, $a \leq m$ for all $a\in A $.

Now I should maybe find a way to show that that inequality is in fact an equality. Or maybe there's an easier way that I don't see.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: what can you say about $m + m$?

Comment: Since the rng has to be closed under addition, $m+m \in A$, but $m$ is an upper bound, so $m+m \leq m$. That implies $m \leq 0$. 

And that implies that 0 is the only element, maybe, because is $m$ is the upper bound and $m \leq 0$, any other element $a$ is such that $a \leq 0$, but in that case, $-a \geq 0$, which cannot be, since that means $a \geq m$

Comment: But wait, $m$ isn't necessarily in $A$.

Comment: If it isn't in $A$, where is it? I think you'll find the question is about the ordered rng $A$ and not about $A$ extended with additional elements that aren't in the domains of the rng operations. (It is possible to set up theories of systems that could involve a rng and an ordered set containing the elements of the rng and other things as well, but I doubt that you are being asked to solve this problem in a context like that.)

Comment: Well, upper or lower bound in a ring means upper or lower bound in the set, right? So, a set $A$ can have a upper bound $m$ and $m \not\in A$. For example, $B = ]-x,x[$ has $x$ as a upper bound, but $x \not\in B$ and it doesn't have a biggest element. I know that set can't be a ring, but you get the idea.

Comment: You are considering a relation between what is technically called the *universe* (or *carrier set*) of the ordered ring and a larger ordered structure that might contain an upper or lower bound for the unverse of the ring. We certainly can make the open interval $B=]-x, x[$ into a ring (by identifying it with $\Bbb{R} = ]-\infty, +\infty[$ under a suitable order-preserving mapping), but $x$ and $-x$ are not elements of the universe of that ring. (Aside: your comments have helped me to understand what "overthinking" means. Thank you.)

Comment: Oh I see, I can't think about that "larger structure" when taking a upper bound in the carrier set. Okay then, thank you!